# Error killing Camera process in ADB, Android R

Tags: android, process, camera, adb, kill

I was trying to kill my camera process in adb (i'm running android R) using this command:

> kill -HUP ps -A | grep camera | awk '{print $2}'

but after i hit enter, it gave me an error:

> /system/bin/sh: kill: ps: arguments must be jobs or process IDs

> /system/bin/sh: kill: -A: arguments must be jobs or process IDs

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use command [`pkill`](https://linuxize.com/post/pkill-command-in-linux/) and learn about `pgrep` as well.

```
pkill -9 -f "camera"
```